# Uploading image from directory and set to a button

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I was wondering if someone could help me, I have  a button that lets a user select an image from the directory. I wanted to know how I can get the image chosen and set it to another button.

```
JButton btnInsertImage = new JButton("Insert image");
btnInsertImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter
            ("JPG AND JPEG", new String[] { "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG" });
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
});

btnInsertImage.setBounds(734, 287, 148, 23);
mammal.add(btnInsertImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but you should be able to just do something like.

```
targetButton.setIcon (new ImageIcon(f.toURI().toURL ()));
```